# Azure Platform Training Kit AspProviders Configuration Error

Tags: azure

I just downloaded the [Windows Azure Platform Training Kit - October Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8396) and all of the examples working with ASP.NET Membership using their AspProviders project throw a Configuration Error exception. I've spent quite a bit of time trying to debug and correct but am stumped, has anyone seen this as well and have a solution?

[image: Configuration Error]

Comment: As annoying as it may be to not find the solution, I'd just move on to the next training exercise.  You don't want to use this session state provider on a production site anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created your Developer Storage with DSInit.exe ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433005.aspx

Comment: The training kit makes no mention on DSInit.exe and the link you posted indicates this command executes automatically when the storage emulator is run; I'm inclined to believe I shouldn't have to run it explicitly. In general I have no problem with storage locally except when trying to use Membership with AspProviders in the examples from Microsoft.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Express Edition? If the answer is no then you must run DSInit.exe once to create the necessary database tables.